# how to give space in text in pdf in iphone app

Tags: iphone, xcode

i have created a pdf in iphone app i want to give some space and then display text

like

Now text look like this

This is the first test

i want the above text should start from here like

```
     This is the first test
```

so how to make this spce below is the code for text showing

```
  CGRect renderingRectNext = CGRectMake(kBorderInset + kMarginInset, kBorderInset + kMarginInset + 70.0, pageSize.width - 2*kBorderInset - 2*kMarginInset, stringSizeNext.height);


 [textToDrawTwo drawInRect:renderingRectNext 
                 withFont:fontNext
            lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap
                alignment:UITextAlignmentLeft];
```

Comment: you can simply put text like this textToDrawTwo = @"       This is the first test";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not quite sure I understand your question, from what I've gathered you want to `skip lines` in the rendered text. If you add `\n` to your string it will skip to the next line.

```
textToDrawTwo = @"\n\nThis is the first test";
```

The bove will produce a string with 2 skipped lines before the actual text.

Hope this helps.

**EDIT:** Additionally, If you wan't to recreate a `tab` like sentence, with spaces before the line of text you would do something like this.

```
textToDrawTwo = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"    %@",textToDrawTwo];
```